# How to make/get a proportional flow control valve

Tags: pwm, servo, robotics

I want to use hydraulic flow to proportionally vary the resistance of a rpi controlled exercise machine.   The victim would rotate a positive displacement pump where the inlet and outlet ports are connected through one or more valves.

I would prefer to use a servo to vary the flow through a single valve.  Integrated servo control valves on ebay are rather expensive.  How practical would it be to attach a servo, say, to a plumbing shutoff valve?

[Solenoid vales](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10456) are cheap by comparison.  I'm considering using only one as a pulse width modulator to vary the flow. I think it would need to be banged open and shut between 5-10 hz for a smooth flow.  Would it likely hold up under that?

Alternatively, a couple could be ganged with harmonically arranged open flows between an outlet and an inlet manifold:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwxEyH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Appreciate feedback/recommendations!

Comment: That seems pretty fast for a solenoid.  Have you estimated the required stroke length? 
   If is short it could go faster.  And the return is via a spring typically.

Comment: About a year ago I played with solenoid valve and found them interesting. Then I wrote some 30+ posts to share my experience. You might be interested to skim through them: (1) Solenod Valve How To - tlfong01 rpi-org-forums:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=231541&hilit=solenoid+valve+tlfong01#p1418054,

(2) Searched query: solenoid valve tlfong01, found 35 matches - rpi.org.ofrums:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/search.php?keywords=solenoid+valve+tlfong01. Cheers.

Comment: You might like to watch my solenoid valve in action: Puroxd12 solenoid valve 2019jan1901:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h3DAcJ07mo4. Cheers.